# Android 2.3, 4.0 rtsp video streaming error: no video, but audio

Tags: android, video, streaming, rtsp, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i have a problem with playback of stream video.

On HTC Desire 2.2 video playing well, no problems
but on Nexus One 2.3.4 and Nexus S 4.0.3 i have only audio, but no video displayed

Here is block log that have equal problem on N1 and NS

```
02-27 11:42:30.914: W/MyHandler(116): Unsupported format. Ignoring track #2.
02-27 11:42:30.914: I/MyHandler(116): SETUP(2) completed with result -1010 (Unknown error: 1010)
```

full log:

```
02-27 11:42:20.634: I/MyHandler(116): connection request completed with result 0 (Unknown error: 0)
02-27 11:42:20.664: I/ARTSPConnection(116): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/MyHandler(116): DESCRIBE completed with result 0 (Unknown error: 0)
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): v=0
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): o=- 952000 952000 IN IP4 178.124.133.2
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): s=WowzaMediaServer
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): i=<No author> <No copyright>
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): t=0 0
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=SdpplinVersion:1610641560
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=StreamCount:integer;2
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=control:*
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=LiveStream:integer;1
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=Title:buffer;"V293emFNZWRpYVNlcnZlcg=="
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=range:npt=0-
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=tool:libavformat 53.5.0
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): m=audio 7234 RTP/AVP 97
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=AS:72
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=TIAS:64000
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=RR:1280
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=RS:640
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=maxprate:16.000000
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=control:streamid=1
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=range:npt=0-
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=length:npt=0
02-27 11:42:20.674: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=rtpmap:97 MP4A-LATM/44100/2
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=41;cpresent=0;config=400024203fc0
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=mimetype:string;"audio/MP4A-LATM"
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=ASMRuleBook:string;"Marker=0,AverageBandwidth=64000,TimestampDelivery=TRUE,InterDepend=1;Marker=1,AverageBandwidth=0,TimestampDelivery=TRUE,InterDepend=0;"
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=3GPP-Adaptation-Support:1
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=Helix-Adaptation-Support:1
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=AvgBitRate:integer;64000
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=ForceRTP:integer;1
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): m=video 7232 RTP/AVP 96
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=AS:208
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=TIAS:200000
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=RR:4000
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=RS:2000
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=maxprate:16.000000
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=control:streamid=2
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=range:npt=0-
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=length:npt=0
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=Z0LAFdoCMK/r/wDTAMcQAAADABAAAAMB4PFi6g==,aM48gA==
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=mimetype:string;"video/H264"
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=ASMRuleBook:string;"Marker=0,AverageBandwidth=200000,TimestampDelivery=TRUE,InterDepend=1;Marker=1,AverageBandwidth=0,TimestampDelivery=TRUE,InterDepend=0;"
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=3GPP-Adaptation-Support:1
02-27 11:42:20.684: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=Helix-Adaptation-Support:1
02-27 11:42:20.694: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=AvgBitRate:integer;200000
02-27 11:42:20.694: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=ForceRTP:integer;1
02-27 11:42:20.704: I/ARTSPConnection(116): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
02-27 11:42:20.704: I/MyHandler(116): SETUP(1) completed with result 0 (Unknown error: 0)
02-27 11:42:20.704: W/MyHandler(116): Missing 'source' field in Transport response. Using RTSP endpoint address.
02-27 11:42:20.704: W/MyHandler(116): Unsupported format. Ignoring track #2.
02-27 11:42:20.714: I/MyHandler(116): SETUP(2) completed with result -1010 (Unknown error: 1010)
02-27 11:42:20.754: I/ActivityManager(163): Displayed by.tut.android/.tv.channelselector.VideoViewActivity: +338ms
02-27 11:42:20.804: I/ARTSPConnection(116): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
02-27 11:42:20.814: I/MyHandler(116): PLAY completed with result 0 (Unknown error: 0)
02-27 11:42:30.824: W/MyHandler(116): Never received any data, switching transports.
02-27 11:42:30.824: I/ARTSPConnection(116): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
02-27 11:42:30.834: I/MyHandler(116): TEARDOWN completed with result 0 (Unknown error: 0)
02-27 11:42:30.844: I/MyHandler(116): connection request completed with result 0 (Unknown error: 0)
02-27 11:42:30.864: I/ARTSPConnection(116): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
02-27 11:42:30.874: I/MyHandler(116): DESCRIBE completed with result 0 (Unknown error: 0)
02-27 11:42:30.874: I/ASessionDescription(116): v=0
02-27 11:42:30.874: I/ASessionDescription(116): o=- 139000 139000 IN IP4 178.124.133.2
02-27 11:42:30.874: I/ASessionDescription(116): s=WowzaMediaServer
02-27 11:42:30.874: I/ASessionDescription(116): i=<No author> <No copyright>
02-27 11:42:30.874: I/ASessionDescription(116): c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
02-27 11:42:30.874: I/ASessionDescription(116): t=0 0
02-27 11:42:30.884: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=SdpplinVersion:1610641560
02-27 11:42:30.884: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=StreamCount:integer;2
02-27 11:42:30.884: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=control:*
02-27 11:42:30.884: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=LiveStream:integer;1
02-27 11:42:30.884: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=Title:buffer;"V293emFNZWRpYVNlcnZlcg=="
02-27 11:42:30.884: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=range:npt=0-
02-27 11:42:30.884: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=tool:libavformat 53.5.0
02-27 11:42:30.884: I/ASessionDescription(116): m=audio 7234 RTP/AVP 97
02-27 11:42:30.884: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=AS:72
02-27 11:42:30.894: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=TIAS:64000
02-27 11:42:30.894: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=RR:1280
02-27 11:42:30.894: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=RS:640
02-27 11:42:30.894: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=maxprate:16.000000
02-27 11:42:30.894: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=control:streamid=1
02-27 11:42:30.894: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=range:npt=0-
02-27 11:42:30.894: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=length:npt=0
02-27 11:42:30.894: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=rtpmap:97 MP4A-LATM/44100/2
02-27 11:42:30.894: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=41;cpresent=0;config=400024203fc0
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=mimetype:string;"audio/MP4A-LATM"
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=ASMRuleBook:string;"Marker=0,AverageBandwidth=64000,TimestampDelivery=TRUE,InterDepend=1;Marker=1,AverageBandwidth=0,TimestampDelivery=TRUE,InterDepend=0;"
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=3GPP-Adaptation-Support:1
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=Helix-Adaptation-Support:1
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=AvgBitRate:integer;64000
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=ForceRTP:integer;1
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): m=video 7232 RTP/AVP 96
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=AS:208
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=TIAS:200000
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=RR:4000
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): b=RS:2000
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=maxprate:16.000000
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=control:streamid=2
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=range:npt=0-
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=length:npt=0
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=Z0LAFdoCMK/r/wDTAMcQAAADABAAAAMB4PFi6g==,aM48gA==
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=mimetype:string;"video/H264"
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=ASMRuleBook:string;"Marker=0,AverageBandwidth=200000,TimestampDelivery=TRUE,InterDepend=1;Marker=1,AverageBandwidth=0,TimestampDelivery=TRUE,InterDepend=0;"
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=3GPP-Adaptation-Support:1
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=Helix-Adaptation-Support:1
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=AvgBitRate:integer;200000
02-27 11:42:30.904: I/ASessionDescription(116): a=ForceRTP:integer;1
02-27 11:42:30.914: I/ARTSPConnection(116): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
02-27 11:42:30.914: I/MyHandler(116): SETUP(1) completed with result 0 (Unknown error: 0)
02-27 11:42:30.914: W/MyHandler(116): Unsupported format. Ignoring track #2.
02-27 11:42:30.914: I/MyHandler(116): SETUP(2) completed with result -1010 (Unknown error: 1010)
02-27 11:42:31.254: I/ARTSPConnection(116): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
02-27 11:42:31.254: I/MyHandler(116): PLAY completed with result 0 (Unknown error: 0)
02-27 11:42:32.866: I/AwesomePlayer(116): ARTSPController::connect returned 0
```

Answer (score 0):

What server is this from? Edit - I just saw WowzaMediaServer

Really, there probably isn't enough information, server logs would also be very helpful.

First off, android changed media servers during these versions, moving from OpenCore to StageFright.

The error is "02-27 11:42:20.704: W/MyHandler(116): Unsupported format. Ignoring track #2"

The android rtp client has returned an error "setting up" the video track. 
The obvious first:
Your SDP file specifies port 7232 "m=video 7232 RTP/AVP 96". Is this port already in use?

According the APacketSource.cpp from the libstagefright the media player, 
The reasons setup can fail with this error are because:
1) No valid picture dimenions in the SDP or the encoded sprops (try manually decoding them) with a base64 tool (and one that supports binary data, not just ascii text)),
2) if using AMR and the sample rate != 8000 and there are more than 1 channel (you are not)
3) if using AMR WB and the sample rate != 16000 and there are more than 1 channel (you are not) 
4) You have a string description which does NOT satisfy one of these else- ifs:
"H264/","H263-2000/","H263-1998/","MP4A-LATM/","AMR/","AMR-WB/", "MP4V-ES/", "mpeg4-generic/"

You have both "H264/90000" AND "video/H264"

I'd lose the "a=mimetype:string;"video/H264"" string in the SDP file and see how it works?? It's a longshot though (But that doesn't explain why the audio works, as it is the same)

While there *shoudn't" be any problem with this, in my experiece with android and RTP/RTSP/SDP so far, stagefright is NOT very good with dealing with extended types, only the bare minumum.

If you want to look the at what I explained above, you can check out the android source code, the files are in "/media/libstagefrigt/rtsp/". The relevant files are MyHandler.h and APacketSource.cpp

UPDATE: You have another/worse problem

I just saw this in your log:
"02-27 11:42:30.824: W/MyHandler(116): Never received any data, switching transports."
and I noticed the two attempts are back to back, rather than what I thought was you copy and pasting two attempts.

There are two problems here, one is the video setup failing, and secondly is the entire first session setup fails.

The "Never received any data, switching transports" error occurs after a 10second timeout between Android issuing the PLAY command, and it not receiving data for 10 seconds. It then tears down the session and attempts to set up the session over TCP.

There is most likely some UDP ports being blocked or not opened on your computer/firewall etc. This causes the first session to fail. It may even explain the reason for the failing video setup. Check what ports the server is trying to use for the video setup. Make sure they are above 1024.

Also, I don't like how your SDP list the audio first, then the video, but the audio uses lower ports than the subsequent video (It's probably fine, just "looks" strange)